# Fill an array with objects from XML

Tags: java

I have a XML file that I am trying to read and transform into objects. I want to transform and put all the locations in a array filled with Location objects wich are defined by a film id, a date and a amount.

Here is my XML file :

Here is my code to scan the location XML section :

```
 public void findLocations() throws ParseException {

    NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("location");
    Location[] locations = new Location[nList.getLength()];
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
              locations[temp] = new Location(getTagValue("filmid", eElement), dateChanger(getTagValue("date", eElement)), getTagValue("amount", eElement));
         System.out.println(locations[temp].getAmount()); //Outputs the good values.
        }

    }
 System.out.println(locations[0].getAmount()); //Output : 5$
 System.out.println(locations[1].getAmount()); //Output : 5$
 System.out.println(locations[2].getAmount()); //Output : 5$
}


private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {

    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

The problem seems that my array is getting filled 3 times with the same location and ends up filled 3 time with the last location. The objects otherwise are well formed, so I imagine I got that part right.

Comment: You have a bug in `getTagValue`. Use a debugger.

Comment: what does you getTagValue method do. Put in that code here

Comment: I added it in the original post.

Comment: Am getting perfect output without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XPath instead...

```
public class TestXML03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(new File("Test.xml"));

            Node root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();

            XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xPath = xFactory.newXPath();

            XPathExpression xExpress = xPath.compile("/file/location");
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xExpress.evaluate(root, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            System.out.println("Found " + nodes.getLength() + " location nodes");
            System.out.println("");

            for (int index = 0; index < nodes.getLength(); index++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(index);
                xExpress = xPath.compile("filmid");
                Node filmIDNode = (Node) xExpress.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODE);
                System.out.println(filmIDNode.getNodeName() + " = " + filmIDNode.getTextContent());

                xExpress = xPath.compile("date");
                Node dateNode = (Node) xExpress.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODE);
                System.out.println(dateNode.getNodeName() + " = " + dateNode.getTextContent());

                xExpress = xPath.compile("amount");
                Node amountNode = (Node) xExpress.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODE);
                System.out.println(amountNode.getNodeName() + " = " + amountNode.getTextContent());

                System.out.println("");
            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Found 3 location nodes

filmid = 100
date = 2013-01-11
amount = 4.00$

filmid = 200
date = 2013-01-13
amount = 9.00$

filmid = 334
date = 2013-01-23
amount = 5.00$
```

**Updated After Feed-back**

The `Location` class is maintaining a `static` reference to it's class fields, this means that changing the value for the field will change it for all instances of that class.

Remove the `static` references and it should solve the problem.

Comment: Nope still not doing what I want. When I put all the locations in a array composed with Locations Objects its still the same film.

    locations[index] = new Reclamation(dateNode.getTextContent(), dateChanger2(filmIDNode.getTextContent()), amountNode.getTextContent());
                System.out.println(reclamations[i++].getFilmId()); //Outputs good film Id in the loop
//Outputs all the same film Id outside the loop

Comment: Then it sounds like there's something wrong with your Location object.  Are you using `static` variables??

Comment: Yes, they are Private Static variables.

Comment: There's your problem.  `static` is a shared variable, meaning that if you change it in one instance, it will be changed for all instances.

Comment: OH ! I see it now, I tough putting this in an array of objects will prevent this. Thank you very much! Do I have to mark this post as the solution ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the comments about `static` references, if you're happy with that, then yes, you should mark it answered (as it will close the question ;))

Answer (score 0):

Your source is working perfectly. Simply modifying your source to output tags as below.

```
public static void findLocations(Document document) throws ParseException {
    NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("location");
    Location[] locations = new Location[nList.getLength()];
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            System.out.println(getTagValue("filmid", eElement));
            System.out.println(getTagValue("date", eElement));
            System.out.println(getTagValue("amount", eElement));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the proper output

```
100
2013-01-11
4.00$

200
2013-01-13
9.00$

334
2013-01-23
5.00$
```

Check if your XML input is proper.

Comment: Thats what I am getting if I use the array to return the values.

System.out.println(locations[0].getAmount()); //Output : 5$